# Проблема c оператором присваивания

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов

На днях решил попрактиковаться работать с классами ,в которых используется динамическая память.Для этого реализовал небольшой класса для работы с векторами.
У меня возникла проблема: при попытке присвоить экземпляру класса другой экземпляр с которым проводились мат операции выдается следующая ошибка:

*E0349  отсутствует оператор "=", соответствующий этим операндам*

Я пробовал перегрузить оператор "=",так чтобы в параметра передавалась копия объекта(знаю,так делать не рекомендуется),но тогда ,при попытке копирования объекта, в аргументы метода компилятор выдает: Не имеется подходящего конструктора копии.

Также при попытке передавать в аргументы методов объект по ссылке на константу ,возникает ошибка(*E1086 Объект содержит квалификаторы типа, несовместимые с элементом функции*) в строчках кода где ведется работа с этим объектом.

Я первый раз обращаюсь за помощью на подобные ресурсы,т.к обычно на решение какой-либо проблемы у меня не уходит больше дня,но здесь мне ничего не приходит в голову.С++ начал изучать недавно,поэтому если найдете какие-то недочеты в код ,то пожалуйста пишите о них.

Сам код:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vector2D
{
private:
    double* x = nullptr;
    double* y = nullptr;


public:

    Vector2D(double x, double y)
    {
        this->x = new double{ x };
        this->y = new double{ y };
    }

    Vector2D(const Vector2D& other)
    {
        if (this->x == nullptr || this->y == nullptr)
        {
            this->x = new double;
            this->y = new double;
        }


        //Объект содержит квалификаторы типа, несовместимые с элементом функции


        *this->x = other.get_x();
        *this->y = other.get_y();
    }

    double get_x()
    {
        return *x;
    }

    double get_y()
    {
        return *y;
    }

    Vector2D& operator =(const Vector2D& other)
    {

        //Объекы содержит квалификаторы типа,несовместимые с элементом функции*


        *this->x = other.get_x(); 
        *this->y = other.get_y();

        return *this;
    }





    template<typename T, class = enable_if_t< (is_same<T, int>::value) || (is_same<T, double>::value) >> Vector2D operator *(T factor)
    {
        Vector2D  result(this->get_x() * factor, this->get_y() * factor);

        return  result;
    }

    ~Vector2D()
    {
        delete x;
        delete y;
    }

    friend void print(Vector2D& obj);
};

void print(Vector2D& obj)
{
    cout << "{" << *obj.x << ";" << *obj.y << "}" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{

    Vector2D a(5, 1);
    Vector2D b(7, 1);

    b = a * 5; // отсутствует оператор "=", соответствующий этим операндам

    print(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: вот вывод наормального компилятора: `a.cpp:24:16: error: 'this' argument to member function 'get_x' has type     'const Vector2D', but function is not marked const` - думаю все понятно

Comment: и еще одна: `a.cpp:62:5: error: second parameter of 'main' (argument array) must be of type      'char **' int main(int argc, char *argv) {`

Comment: *найдете какие-то недочеты в код* - основной недочет тут в том, что не приведен [mcve]. Если бы вы потрудились его привести, то источник проблемы наверняка стал бы очевиден и вопрос бы даже не потребовался.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Следующий код компилируется (добавил const функциям-членам и включил заголовочные файлы):

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Vector2D
{
private:
    double* x = nullptr;
    double* y = nullptr;


public:

    Vector2D(double x, double y)
    {
        this->x = new double{ x };
        this->y = new double{ y };
    }

    Vector2D(const Vector2D& other)
    {
        if (this->x == nullptr || this->y == nullptr)
        {
            this->x = new double;
            this->y = new double;
        }


        //Объект содержит квалификаторы типа, несовместимые с элементом функции


        *this->x = other.get_x();
        *this->y = other.get_y();
    }

    double get_x() const 
    {
        return *x;
    }

    double get_y() const
    {
        return *y;
    }

    Vector2D& operator =(const Vector2D& other)
    {

        //Объекы содержит квалификаторы типа,несовместимые с элементом функции*


        *this->x = other.get_x(); 
        *this->y = other.get_y();

        return *this;
    }





    template<typename T, class = enable_if_t< (is_same<T, int>::value) || (is_same<T, double>::value) >> Vector2D operator *(T factor)
    {
        Vector2D  result(this->get_x() * factor, this->get_y() * factor);

        return  result;
    }

    ~Vector2D()
    {
        delete x;
        delete y;
    }

    friend void print(Vector2D& obj);
};

void print(Vector2D& obj)
{
    cout << "{" << *obj.x << ";" << *obj.y << "}" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv)
{

    Vector2D a(5, 1);
    Vector2D b(7, 1);

    b = a * 5; // отсутствует оператор "=", соответствующий этим операндам

    print(b);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: добавте текстовое пояснение - приведение кода без описания не приветствуется. Тем более что сдесь проблема всего в одном квалификаторе

Comment: и раз уж приводите весь код, то пофиксите и проблему с `main`

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch что добавить? ошибки в коде комментариями написаны

Comment: исправления опишите - так этот ответ может быть полезен не только ТС, но и другим. Тем более даже для ТС будет лучше, если он будет знать что было изменено без использования `diff`